# Should I wait for SharePoint 2013 or I should go with SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I want to build a new SharePoint system for my organization (internal system) and I read a lot of articles that version 2013 offers some features that worth to have especially when building Apps. But others say that going with SharePoint version 2010 will be more robust and less errors and safer. So in my case our project is for internal use and I can wait a couple of weeks till Microsoft publish the SP 2013, so I have the following questions:-

1. Is it better to wait for version 2013 or It is better to start with version 2010?
2. I find a lot of organization which already use SP 2013 and they have made successful implementations, so if we compare the stability of SP 2010 & 2013 should they be the same?
3. Can anyone recommend what is the best approach to follow in my case bearing in mind the following :-

   - SP will be implemented for our organization  internal use
   - There is no specific deadline
   - Our team did not work before on any version of SP, but we have good skills and experience in building asp.net web applications (web forms and MVC).

Best Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my 2 cents...

1. Is it better to wait for version 2013 or It is better to start with version 2010? - You don't need to wait...you can get a developer version of SP2013 online for free right now...I've been using it for nearly a month - [Sign up for an Office 365 Developer Site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/fp179924.aspx)
2. I find a lot of organization which already use SP 2013 and they have made successful implementations, so if we compare the stability of SP 2010 & 2013 should they be the same? This will depend on which verison of each you are running online or onpremise.  I have noticed with SP2013 online that there has been the occaisional glitch but then this is during the process of me actually developing and deploying stuff so that may be down to my code. Seems pretty stable to me.
3. For me SP2013 is WAY better to develop for both from a UI POV (responsive design is possible now and relatively easy using twitter bootstrap) and from a code development POV although there is a lot to get your head round with regards to the options available for development. Good explanation exists here - [App Designs in SharePoint 2013](http://www.shillier.com/archive/2013/02/27/app-designs-in-sharepoint-2013.aspx)

Hope this helps.

S

Answer (score 1):

> 1.Is it better to wait for version 2013 or It is better to start with version 2010?

2010, its cheaper and the support is still there for quite some time. The ui is similar to 2013 and so when you ugrade to 2013 its not as dificult like compared to 2007. The support for 2010 is better as its been out for longer! considering that your team arnt sharepoint developers I would just jump in the deep end and going to 2013 where the community support is still low!

> 2.I find a lot of organization which already use SP 2013 and they have made successful implementations, so if we compare the stability of SP
>   2010 & 2013 should they be the same?

Yes they are the same pritty much! sharepoint 2013 is just an upgrade using the latest .net 4.5 with some extra features. Also to factor in is not just the price but also the resources...2013 uses ALOT compared to 2010.

im sure there are other factors involved. but for a small enterprise i would recommend to 2010.. support is strong.. microsoft support is still there till next version of sharepoint after 2013.. uses less resources... 2010 has same features as 2013 (2013 obviously has more ;) ).. your brand new to sharepoint and its not simple to just move over even tho you do asp.net doesnt mean you can do sharepoint ;) just means it wont be as difficult :) . MVC will help you out tho when you have complex situations using webservices! Appart from that you should be fine.

I would recommend that you learn some admin side of things as it will come in hand:

vast resources for developers:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/bb964529.aspx

for IT Pros

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/ff465365.aspx

sharepoint msdn documentation administration

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd776256(v=office.12).aspx

learn powershell!

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ee539977(v=office.14).aspx

that should be way more than enough to get you going! if your mainly going to use oob (out of the box) than you should be fine ;) adding custome features and webparts isnt dificult....

if in dout or stuck just post on this site or msdn forum :)

Answer (score 1):

I'd say go with 2013 because you say you have the following freedoms:

- SP will be implemented for our organization internal use
- There is no specific deadline

I'd say that the opposites of those would be among the strongest reasons to go with 2010 :)